# Replace text with input data

Tags: sql-server

How can I achieve this?

ValidationMessage table:

```
ValidationMessageID | Text
1                   | Item(s) <ItemList> do not exist in project <ProjectID>.
5                   | This value <Value> is invalid.
```

ReplacementValues table:

```
ValidationMessageID | ReplacementValues | Index
1  | <614882,614889>,<8068637>          | 10
1  | <614882>,<8068634>                 | 11
1  | <614883>,<8068639>                 | 12
5  | <John Smith>                       | 22
```

Expected Result:

```
ValidationText                                              | Index
Item(s) 614882,614889 do not exist in project <8068637>.    | 10
Item(s) 614882 do not exist in project <8068634>.           | 11
Item(s) 614883 do not exist in project <8068639>.           | 12
This value John Smith is invalid.                           | 22
```

Comment: You would be better considering how you will achieve things like this within SQL Server's limited range of string processing capabilities before designing the structure. For example you might want to look at the `FORMATMESSAGE` function but that will require changes to your strings in  ValidationMessage

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! You should **always** include your version of SQL Server when asking questions here. You might find [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4884/sql-server-2016-stringsplit-function/) interesting! You should put @MartinSmith in your message to ensure that he sees it!

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't mind changing the strings in ValidationMessage to have '%s' instead. How would I achieve this with FORMATMESSAGE?

Comment: I would also change how replacement values are stored so that it can just be used without needing to parse out the components from it. So like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ea0067538dbe96f2a58ca207f263ad0. Otherwise you would need similar but with more hassle to parse the components out of the delimited string

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you! I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The native string processing functions in TSQL are not very sophisticated and this approach requires parsing of the validation message to find items delimited by angle brackets.

Then it requires splitting the ReplacementValue by comma (but not if the comma is inside an angle bracket) and finally removing the angle brackets and doing the replacement for each place holder by corresponding ordinal position.

This could be done in TSQL but would likely require some poor performing scalar UDF - or alternatively would need to call out to CLR/Java code for more advanced string processing capabilities.

I suggest restructuring as follows

```
CREATE TABLE ValidationMessage 
(
ValidationMessageID int primary key,
Text varchar(2000)
)


insert into ValidationMessage
values 
(1,'Item(s) %s do not exist in project %s.'),
(5,'This value %s is invalid.');


CREATE TABLE ReplacementValues
(
ValidationMessageID INT, 
[Index] INT,
Param1 VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
Param2 VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
Param3 VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
Param4 VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
Param5 VARCHAR(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO ReplacementValues(ValidationMessageID, [Index], Param1,Param2)
VALUES 
(1,10,'614882,614889','8068637'),
(1,11,'614882','8068634'),
(1,12,'614883','8068639'),
(5,22,'John Smith', NULL);
```

With an eye on making the final query simple with available functions

```
SELECT VM.ValidationMessageID,
       FORMATMESSAGE(Text, Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, Param5),
       [Index]
FROM   ValidationMessage VM
       JOIN ReplacementValues RV
         ON RV.ValidationMessageID = VM.ValidationMessageID
```

[db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ea0067538dbe96f2a58ca207f263ad0)